# r.sun.daily - WARNING: Unable to rename null/cell file [...] to [...]: File exists (GRASS GIS 7.0.4)

Tags: windows-7, grass-7.0, 64bit

When running the r.sun.daily ([link](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.sun.daily.html)) addon for GRASS GIS 7.0.4, which is a script to run the r.sun module in a loop, I get this error:

```
WARNING: Unable to rename null file 'C:\Users\.../.tmp/unknown/3560.1' to C:\Users\.../cell_misc/Beamtest/null': File exists

WARNING: Unable to rename cell file 'C:\Users\.../.tmp/unknown/8584.0' to 'C:\Users\.../fcell/Beamtest': File exists
```

While the script is able to finish. It returns this error multiple times. So it seems that it is unable to return separate rasters for each loop of r.sun for each of the requested output file. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Below is the code I use to run to script:

```
r.sun.daily --overwrite elevation=taastrupDEM2clip@User aspect=taastrupAspect@User slope=taastrupSlope@User lat=taastrupLat@User long=taastrupLon@User horizon_basename=horangle horizon_step=11.25 beam_rad=taastrupBeamtest diff_rad=taastrupDiffusetest refl_rad=taastrupReflectedtest glob_rad=taastrupGlobaltest start_day=1 end_day=3 day_step=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, instead of using the regular output parameters I had to add the suffix of ´_basename´ to each. With this it correclty creates numbered outputs.

So instead of:

```
r.sun.daily --o elevation=taastrupDEM2clip@User aspect=taastrupAspect@User slope=taastrupSlope@User lat=taastrupLat@User long=taastrupLon@User horizon_basename=horangle horizon_step=11.25 beam_rad_basename=taastrupBeamtest diff_rad_basename=taastrupDiffusetest refl_rad_basename=taastrupReflectedtest glob_rad_basename=taastrupGlobaltest start_day=1 end_day=3 day_step=1 nprocs=4
```

it should say:

```
r.sun.daily --o elevation=taastrupDEM2clip@User aspect=taastrupAspect@User slope=taastrupSlope@User lat=taastrupLat@User long=taastrupLon@User horizon_basename=horangle horizon_step=11.25 beam_rad_basename=taastrupBeamtest diff_rad_basename=taastrupDiffusetest refl_rad_basename=taastrupReflectedtest glob_rad_basename=taastrupGlobaltest start_day=1 end_day=3 day_step=1 nprocs=4
```